# How to share a photo to Instagram with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to share a taken photo to Instagram. I have installed the [social share plugin from ngCordova website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/)

But I am not able to get it to work. When running it I get no errors. 
I get a success response but the image is not posted on the wall of Instagram.

Here is a print screen from the logs (xcode -> running from actual device to test).
[image]

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Here is part of my controller code:

```
app.controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaSocialSharing, $rootScope, $state){

  $scope.takePicture = function(){
    var options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        correctOrientation:true
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options) 
      .then(function(imageURI){
          var imagePlaceholder = document.getElementById('placeholderPicture');
          imagePlaceholder.src = imageURI;
          $rootScope.imgShare = imageURI;
          //$scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
          //$state.go('app.camera', {image: $scope.imgURI});
          //console.log('camera data: ' + angular.toJson(imageURI));
      },  function(error){
          console.log('error camera data: ' + angular.toJson(imageURI));
    });
  }

$scope.shareViaInstagram = function(message, image){
    socialType = "instagram";
    message = "test";
    image = $rootScope.imgShare;

     $cordovaSocialSharing.shareVia(socialType, message, image, null).then(function(result) {
      console.log('image shared to Instagram ', result);
      console.log('dddd', image);
      console.log('######', $rootScope.imgShare);
      //$state.go('app.finish');
}, function(err) {
      console.log('error in sharing to Instagram ', err);
});

  }

});
```

Part of my html code:

```
<div class="wrapperCamera">
        <div class="cameraContent padding">
            <img id="placeholderPicture" ng-src="{{imgShare}}">
            <br>
            <h2 class="customH2Camera">looking good!</h2>
            <br><br>
            <div class="socialIcons">
                <a href="" ng-click="shareViaInstagram(null, null, imgShare, null)"><img src="img/iconInstagram.svg" width="40"></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="" ng-click="shareViaFacebook(null, null, imgShare, null)"><img src="img/iconFacebook.svg" width="40"></a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end cameraContent -->
    </div><!-- end WrapperCamera -->
```

Comment: May be you are missing ng-cordova ?

Comment: nope i added it in my app.js file

Comment: Please add error that you are getting to the question.

Comment: @HardikVaghani. thats the thing i am not getting an error

Comment: try to wrap method with `try-catch` block.

Comment: you use canShareVia which doesn't share, but only checks if you can share. You need to use shareVia method

Comment: @BartekCichocki. mmm its not seeming to work

Comment: @BartekCichocki, by changing it to ShareVia. when i click the instagram icon. i am not logging anything in my console. so now the whole icon/button is not working...

Comment: I haven't used Instagram by this plugin (only FB and Whatsapp), but as I see in doc maybe try method shareViaInstagram(message, link) as in example: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#instagram (also check the quirks in docs about whitelisting)

Comment: @BartekCichocki, i followed along with the url you gave me and added a canShareVia and then a shareViaInstagram but i am still getting the same result (no image posted but i am getting my success callback) ...

Answer (score 1):

```
  module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaInstagram) {
      // Get image from camera, base64 is good. See the
      // $cordovaCamera docs for more info
        $cordovaInstagram.share($scope.image.data, $scope.image.caption).then(function() {
        // Worked
      }, function(err) {
        // Didn't work
      });
    })
```

Comment: And u Need to add this Plugin.. (cordova plugin add https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin.git)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your plugin call within the deviceready event of cordova. It makes sure that device is fully loaded before making a call to the plugin.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { 
  // your plugin call here 
});
```

You can also use `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {});`

Read this for more info: [ngCordova common issues](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/)